# How to evaluate these $4$ integrals?

Tags: integration

> \begin{align}
> (1) & \int \frac{\sqrt{x^4 + \frac{1}{x^4} + 2}}{x^3}dx\\
> (2) & \int \sqrt{1 - \sin(2x)}dx & \forall x \in [-\pi/4, \pi/4]\\
> (3) & \int \cos^2(2x) \cos(x)dx\\
> (4) & \int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x +1}(x+5)}
> \end{align}

I'd be very grateful for any help and hints!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$1$. $\sqrt{x^4 + \dfrac1{x^4} + 2} = x^2 + \dfrac1{x^2}$.

$2$. $\sqrt{1-\sin(2x)} = \sqrt{\cos^2(x) + \sin^2(x) -2 \sin(x) \cos(x)} = \cos(x) - \sin(x)\,\,\, \forall x \in [-\pi/4,\pi/4]$.

$3$. $\cos^2(2x) \cos(x) = \dfrac{1+\cos(4x)}2 \cdot \cos(x) = \dfrac{\cos(x)}2 + \dfrac{\cos(5x) - \cos(3x)}4$.

$4$. $\dfrac{dx}{\sqrt{x+1} (x+5)} \underset{\sqrt{x+1} = t}{\to} \dfrac{2tdt}{t(t^2+4)} = \dfrac{2dt}{t^2+4} = d \left(\arctan \left(\dfrac{t}2 \right)\right)$

Comment: impressive. for speed.

Comment: @user1709828 Marvis tends to be very impressive when it comes to speed... :)